# Questions about Microsoft Point-to-Point Compression(MPPC)?

Tags: compression

I doing some work about compression under the protocol of MPPC.What i can find about this protocol on Internet is the only RFC2118.

In this RFC, i got some thing that i can not understant.

1.Following is the description about the packet format of MPPC.

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |         PPP Protocol          |A|B|C|D| Coherency Count       |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |        Compressed Data...
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

well, then this document tells that Bit A means initializing the history buf,Bit C means "this is a compressed packet", and the Bit D is always set "0".

However, what i capctured in Wireshark is somewhat like this:

```
0000   xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx fd  ...C...<=....j0@
0010   90 00 dd 43 ed bf e9 3c 3d b1 bc fe 07 6a 30 40  ...C...<=....j0@
0020   c8 8e 15 c6 f8 3d 5a 27 6d 24 db 37 be f8 c9 e5  .....=Z'm$.7....
0030   28 ae 0e 85 3a ae 15 32 10 ed ce d4              (...:..2....
```

0xfd is the value of "PPP Protocol".It should be 0x00fd, but compressed to 0xfd.
Following is 0x90 00, being 1001 0000 0000 0000. So,Bit A is 1,Bit B is 0,Bit C is 0, and Bit D is 1.

The following 0000 0000 0000 is the  Coherency Count,it is all right.

Every packet i captured by Wireshark shows the same thing, 0xfd90.But it's must be someting wrong about it,isn't it? Every Packet's Bit A is 1? And Every packet's Bit D is 1?

Any one can gives me some advices about this question?

2.The second question is about the algorithm.

I just paste the words from rfc2118.

"

The compressor runs through the length of the frame producing as
   output a Literal (byte to be sent uncompressed) or a  Copy tuple, where Offset is the number of bytes
   before in the history where the match lies and Length-of-Match is the
   number of bytes to copy from the location indicated by Offset.

For example, comsider the following string:

```
   0         1         2         3         4
   012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
   for whom the bell tolls, the bell tolls for thee.

   The compressor would produce:

   for whom the bell tolls,<16,15> <40,4><19,3>e.
```

"

SO,where is the "16","40",and "19" come from ?

### I'm troubled by this question for days.

This is the first QUESTION i post here, I'm not sure if i made it clear?
But I will preciate it if any one provide some helps.THX!

Answer (score 1):

Will, I find out the answers.
I made a mistack.I will explane it, hoping it will help someone just troubled like me .

Q1:
I think the packet i captured is encrypted. I captured some more packets , and it turns out right.

Q2:
Earlier, I keep considering the "offset" is offset from the head of History string, then i finaly find out it in fact means "back from the current pointer pointing to the History string".

I will edit my Question's title.Hoping it helpful to some one else.